# A PostgreSQL row to keep track of added (created) date and changed date

Tags: database, postgresql

I would like to create a table which stores English idioms and their description however I would like to store when each idiom was added or updated, so I can later sort in the application by date added, etc..

My question is: should I let PostgreSQL add the date time stamp by using its built-in functions and create fields of type DATE? or should I create columns with TEXT type and format/add the date/time in the application itself.

Comment: Never store date or timestamp values in a text column. Use `timestamp` or `date` (depending whether you want the time or not)

Comment: I need both the date and time. So, should I use `timestamp` with a DATE type column?

Comment: use timestamp column datatype without/with timezone. Please check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: You need to use the `timestamp` data type, not a `date`

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your time. I came across this website which explains this subject in more detail: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-timestamp I post it here in hope that it will help others.